# Prove or disprove that $BC(\Bbb R )$ is a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples, inner-products

I have an exercise that says:

> Let $BC(\Bbb R )$ the set of bounded and continuous functions from $\Bbb R $ to $\mathbb{F}$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is $\Bbb R $ or $\Bbb C $, endorsed with the following inner product
>   $$
> \langle f,g \rangle:=\sum_{m\geqslant 1}\frac{f(q_m)\overline{g(q_m)}}{2^m}\tag1
> $$
>   where $(q_m)$ is an enumeration of $\Bbb Q $. Prove or disprove that $BC(\Bbb R )$ is a Hilbert space with this inner product.

I want to check if my counterexample below is correct and maybe if there is a more simple or straightforward counterexample.

I used the following theorem to construct my counterexample:

> **Theorem:** let $(x_k)$ some sequence in a normed vector space $V$. Then $V$ is a Banach space if and only if $\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\|x_k\|<\infty\Rightarrow \sum_{k\geqslant 0}x_k$ exists in $V$.

Then assuming that
$$
\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\|g_k\|=\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\sqrt{\sum_{m\geqslant 1}\frac{|g_k(q_m)|^2}{2^m}}<\infty\tag2
$$
we want to show that $\sum_{k\geqslant 1}g_k$ doesn't belong to $BC(\Bbb R)$.

Let a sequence $(g_k)$ in $BC(\Bbb R )$ defined by $g_k(x)=0$ if $x\notin [k,k+1)$ and $\|g_k\|_\infty =g_k(k+1/2)=k$ and let $(p_k)$ the increasing sequence of primes (that is, $p_0=2,\, p_1=3,\,p_2=5$, and so on) and define $N_k:=\{p_k^n: n\in \Bbb N_{>0}\}$. Then $(N_k)$ is a disjoint sequence of infinite subsets of $\Bbb N $ and because $p_k> k$ for all $k\in \Bbb N_{\geqslant 0} $ then we find that $\sum_{x\in N_k}2^{-x}< 2^{-k}$.

Then there is an injection $b:\Bbb Q \to \Bbb N$ such that the image of $b$ restricted to the set $[k,k+1)\cap \Bbb Q $ is $N_k$. Then by construction we find that
$$
\sum_{q\in \Bbb Q }\frac{|g_k(q)|^2}{2^{b(q)}}\leqslant\frac{k^2}{2^k}\implies  \sum_{k\geqslant 1}\|g_k\|\leqslant \sum_{k\geqslant 1}\frac{k}{2^{k/2}}< \infty\tag3
$$
However $g:=\sum_{k\geqslant 1}g_k$ is unbounded because $g(k+1/2)=k$ for all $k\in \Bbb N $, then by the theorem stated above $BC(\Bbb R )$ cannot be a Banach space, neither a Hilbert space.

---

### UPDATE:

As pointed by @Daniel my counterexample is not right because it must work for any enumeration of the rationals and not just for a chosen enumeration.

Then I want to show that, for any enumeration of $\Bbb Q $, we can build a sequence $(f_k)$ with a similar behavior of the sequence $(g_k)$ of above. Let an enumeration $(q_n)_n$ of $\Bbb Q $ and set $Q_n:=\max\{q_1,\ldots ,q_n\}$ and define recursively the sequence of open intervals
$$
I_1:=(q_1,q_1+1)\\
I_n:=(\max\{\sup I_{n-1},Q_n\},\max\{\sup I_{n-1},Q_n\}+1)\tag4
$$
Then by construction $(I_n)$ is a sequence of disjoint intervals of length one with the property that $\{q_1,\ldots ,q_n\}\cap I_n=\emptyset $. Now we set a sequence $(f_k)$ on $BC(\Bbb R )$ by $f_k(x)=0$ when $x\notin I_k$ and $\|f_k\|_\infty =k$. Then, by construction, each function $f_k$ have disjoint support and
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant 1 }\frac{|f_k(q_n)|^2}{2^n}=\sum_{n\geqslant k+1}\frac{|f_k(q_n)|^2}{2^n}\leqslant \sum_{n\geqslant k+1}\frac{k^2}{2^n}=\frac{k^2}{2^k}\\
\therefore \quad \sum_{k\geqslant 1}\|f_k\|\leqslant \sum_{k\geqslant 1}\frac{k}{2^{k/2}}<\infty \tag5
$$
However by construction we have that for each $k\in \Bbb N $ there is some $x\in I_k$ such that $f_k(x)=k$, hence $\sum_{k\geqslant 1}f_k$ is unbounded, and by the theorem stated above it shows that $BC(\Bbb R )$ cannot be a Hilbert space.

Comment: It doesn't quite work, because the enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ could happen to have (for example) $q_1 = p_{123456}^{9876543} + \frac{1}{2}$. You need to pick the places where $g_k$ is large depending on the enumeration $(q_m)$. But the general idea works, it just needs more fiddling.

Comment: @Daniel I dont follow your comment, sorry. Could you say what step of my example doesn't hold to try to follow what you mean? Oh, I think I get what you mean: I used an ad-hoc enumeration of the rational numbers, what could not be the same enumeration of the inner product, right?

Comment: I misunderstood what you're doing. The problem with your construction is (if I haven't again misunderstood it) that you're not using the given (arbitrary) enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ to construct your $g_k$, but you're constructing a sort-of-enumeration in order to get a suitable bound for $\sum \lVert g_k\rVert$. There's no reason to believe that you have $b(q_m) = m$ for $q_m \in [k,k+1)$.

Comment: @Daniel yes, you are right, thank you for commenting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your modified construction works.

Here is another way to prove that $BC(\mathbb{R})$ is not complete with respect to $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$:

We know that $BC(\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space with respect to the supremum norm $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_{\infty}$. Now for $g \in BC(\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$\lVert g\rVert = \sqrt{\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} 2^{-m}\lvert g(q_m)\rvert^2}
\leqslant \sqrt{\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} 2^{-m}\lVert g\rVert_{\infty}^2} = \lVert g\rVert_{\infty}\,.$$
Thus the identity is a continuous linear bijection $\bigl(BC(\mathbb{R}),\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_{\infty}\bigr) \to \bigl(BC(\mathbb{R}),\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert\bigr)$, and the result follows by the open mapping theorem as soon as we have shown that the norms aren't equivalent.

There are many ways to do that. The easiest way I see is to consider functions $f_n\in BC(\mathbb{R})$ with $\lVert f_n\rVert_{\infty} = 1$ but $f_n(q_m) = 0$ for $m \leqslant n$, whence $\lVert f_n\rVert \leqslant 2^{-n/2}$.

Comment: Moderately said $\color{teal}\blacklozenge$ which is not mine $\color{teal}\blacklozenge$ this is *GREAT stuff !* $\;$Even so just one $\uparrow\ldots$